# Calculating line length to both sites in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, distance, function

Is there a function or a plugin for QGIS that works like this?

- I have a line, for example, 7 km
- I click on that line at any point
- A popup or something gives me the distance to the left an to the
  right, e.g. `3 km` and `4 km`.

This function is available in [Locus](https://www.locusmap.eu/), an Android App some of you might know.